# Does a ratio of PDFs have any usable meaning?

Tags: soft-question, brownian-motion

I'm calculating the probability that a standard Brownian motion path will cross a boundary.

I have $A$ and $B$ representing the PDFs for the Brownian motion going above a boundary function $a$ and for going below a boundary function $b$, respectively. Clearly, $a$ and $b$ are functions of time, and so are the PDFs, so I can't examine a single value, I have to take an average, so I did the easiest thing I could come up with, I used,

$$P_a={1 \over L} \cdot \int_0^L {A \over {A+B}} \ dt$$

For the probability the Brownian motion hits the boundary $a$ rather than $b$. If the PDFs become constant as I take $L$ to infinity, I can justify this. But, what about if $L$ is finite and the PDFs vary? For instance, take $a$ and $b$ to be half domes.

Basically, how do I probabilisticly interpret this ratio integral?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling comes to mind.

Comment: Basically, in importance sampling, you have a random variable $X$ with PDF $f$ and you want to compute $E[g(X)]=\int g(x) f(x) dx$. To do that, you introduce a new variable $Y$ with PDF $h$, and you write $\int g(x) f(x) dx = \int \frac{g(x) f(x) h(x)}{h(x)} dx$ (where for this purpose you interpret 0/0 as 0). Thus $E[g(X)]=E\left [\frac{g(Y) f(Y)}{h(Y)} \right ]$. Then hopefully $\frac{g(Y) f(Y)}{h(Y)}$ has a low variance. (I don't think this has much to do with your problem, but it is relevant to your title.)